# Color images load in black and white before turning full color

Tags: wordpress

Large hero background color images at the top of pages on this website:

[https://patelaw.staging.wpengine.com/](https://patelaw.staging.wpengine.com)

are loading in black in white first and then becoming full color. I looked into the plugins to see if any of them might be the culprit and I don't think any of the plugins are doing it.

The plugins on the site even remotely related to images are:

- Beaver Builder
- Yoast
- Shadowbox
- Short Pixel

I can't figure out why it's happening and would be grateful for any suggestions.
I'm on Mac 10.11.6 and seeing this issue on Chrome. Chrome Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Have you fixed it? They're all in colour for me.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @Peter, I think it may be a Chrome issue. They don't load in black and white and then turn to full color on Firefox and Safari (I haven't tested Edge).